# Vilvaldi can't found Python

Tags: raspbian-jessie, python-2.x

hello there fam I am using a python code to open a specific link like this using a webbrowser module

code is this:

```
webbrowser.get("vivaldi").open('http://127.0.0.1/raspi/invalid.php?error=403')
```

but return the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "read.py", line 47, in <module>
    main()
  File "read.py", line 40, in main
    webbrowser.get("vivaldi-stable").open('http://127.0.0.1/raspi/invalid.php?error=403')
  File "/usr/lib/python2.7/webbrowser.py", line 52, in get
    raise Error("could not locate runnable browser")
webbrowser.Error: could not locate runnable browser
```

Comment: Are you sure Vivaldi is installed and working?

Comment: yes I donwload the .deb file of vivaldi then install using the command "sudo dpgk -i /path of deb/"

Comment: @VincentP is probably wondering if you have been able to get Vivaldi to do *anything at all* successfully?

Comment: yes I run vivaldi browser but when use in python said can't found the runnable browser